# jQuery wrap breaks CSS pseudo elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Alright so for a site I am working on I am creating these image piles. I am trying to have so I can just grab an `<img>` then wrap it with the a div and have the css I set up take care of styling it to give it the image pile effect.

Here is a link to a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/stewbydoo/39HKr/5/). And here is the main part of the code.

```
(function ($){
    $.fn.ImagePile = function (options) {
        var settings = $.extend({
            pileType: "neat"
        }, options);
        //get pileType from settings
        var pileType = settings.pileType;

        switch(pileType){
            case "neat":
                return this.wrap("<div class='stack neat'></div>");
                break;
        }
    };
})(jQuery);


$("#image1").ImagePile();
```

Forgot to mention that the problem is the `:after` element is not showing up where it is supposed to be showing up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're not setting a `left` or `right` attribute for the absolutely positioned items, then it defaults to `auto` which is fine for the `:before` element but obviously not the `:after` element.

Just try setting a `left` or `right` attribute for the `:before` and `:after` in your CSS.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/39HKr/6/